# How do I use SASS/SCSS with Django Zurb Foundation?

Tags: django, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm new with SASS/SCSS and I want to add it to my Django project. I have installed django-zurb-foundation 5.3.0.1 and went to example.com/scss/ and got the following error:

'compress' is not a valid tag library: Template library compress not found.

I've tried several plugins but just don't know how i can fix this error properly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but this is what I did.

1. i installed compass and zurb-foundation.
   a.) gem install compass,
   b.) gem install zurb-foundation
2. then make sure you're inside your file before you type:

   a.) compass create [folder] -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
   (this will download all the foundation file to the folder.)
3. then cd to your folder where you intend to put your sass.
4. lastly: sass --watch sass:css (this just means sass watch the folder "sass" and any changes inside of "sass" make the changes in css)

Hopefully that helps. I didn't encounter any error with template. It was quite automatic with Django.

Comment: I installed foundation with 'pip install django-zurb-foundation'. Don't know for sure if it will work in this situation, but I'll try!

Comment: cool! But what helped? your django-zurb-foundation? because honestly, I didn't need to install that one.

Comment: No I already had django-zurb-foundation installed at the beginning of my project. So I just followed your steps and it worked. At first I had some doubts because I read your solution wrong.